# How do I display image from api in json?

Tags: html, json

I am calling betterdoctor api and im getting back data and i am trying to display a image from the json data. But all im getting back is the src of the image.How do i display the image? instead of just the src of image.

```
for(i=0;i<data.data.length;i++){
list = list +
'<div class="user">' +
   '<p>' +data.data[i]['profile']['first_name']+ " " +data.data[i]
    ['profile']['last_name']+'</p>' +
   '<p>' + 'latitude is ' + data.data[i]['practices'][0]['lat']+ '</p>' 
    +
   '<p>' + 'longtitude is ' + data.data[i]['practices'][0]['lon']+ 
   '</p>' +
   <img src= data.data[i]['profile']['image_url'] alt="Mountain View">
   +
   '</div>' 
    }
```

Comment: `<img src="whatever-url.com/image.png">`

Comment: I tried that and it doesnt work. Your suggestion is not helpful.

Comment: Your code above does not show you putting the image_url inside an image tag.   Can you show us your code where you tried that?

Comment: the image source is inside <img>

Comment: Your code is not properly quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Robby Cornelissen comment, you probably want to put the URL inside a img tag.

```
for(i=0;i<data.data.length;i++){
list = list +
'<div class="user">' +
   '<p>' +data.data[i]['profile']['first_name']+ " " +data.data[i]
    ['profile']['last_name']+'</p>' +
   '<p>' + 'latitude is ' + data.data[i]['practices'][0]['lat']+ '</p>' 
    +
   '<p>' + 'longtitude is ' + data.data[i]['practices'][0]['lon']+ 
   '</p>' +
   '<p><img src="' + data.data[i]['profile']['image_url'] + '"/></p>' +
   '</div>' 
    }
```